# How to highlight text in file, separated by blank lines, that begins with certain string in Python?

Tags: python, colors, text-files, transcription

I've got a text file with an interview transcript, where I want to change colour or highlight everything that only an interviewee was saying. The text that I want to highlight always begins with certain string of characters and the whole text to be highlighted is separated by empty lines. Something like this:

BBB: Text to remain black.Text to remain black.Text to remain black.Text to remain black.Text to remain black.Text to remain black.Text to remain black.Text to remain black.

AAA: text in different colour.text in different colour.text in different colour.text in different colour.
text in different colour.text in different colour.text in different colour.text in different colour.text in different colour.

BBB: Text to remain black.Text to remain black.Text to remain black.Text to remain black.
Text to remain black.Text to remain black.
Text to remain black.

Hope this makes sense! Thanks :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('myfile','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line[0:3] == 'AAA':
            print(f"\033[1;32;40m{line[3:]}")
        if line[0:3] == 'BBB':
            print(f'\033[0;37;40m{line}')
```

That works if you want the color change in printing.

Comment: Thank you! But it doesn't work unfortunately. I need to write these coloured lines into a text file (.rtf). It should write the same lines from original file, with only relevant paragraphs coloured. 

I also tried this with no success:

from colorama import Fore
if my_name in line.strip("\n"):
     line = line.replace(line, Fore.RED + line)